# Remove tags, add new ones

Tags: discussion, tags

In relation to [What security features should a smart TV have?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117951/what-security-features-should-a-smart-tv-have) I would recommend removing the `smart` and `TV` tags and replacing them with `IoT` and or `IoT-Device`

Comment: I went ahead and edited the post to have [smart-tv] instead [smart] and [tv] - that was probably what OP intended anyway, and the tag [smart] on its own makes no sense at all. I don't know if further action is needed, but I felt that this was at least a step in the right direction. If anybody wants to rollback, feel free to do so.

Comment: Awesome! Yea that is what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 3):

We actually have the option of synonyms for tags, and I don't really want to remove smart-tv as it is a useful search term, so it may be better to create iot and set smart-tv as a synonym.

Comment: That would make sense to me. With that said `TV` and `smart` probably should be merged to `smart-tv`.

Comment: How do I formally suggest or make these edits / modifications?

Comment: But any reason at all to leave [tag:smart] and [tag:tv]? Also how do we remove tag creation privileges from users that abuse them.